# Cubic spline interpolation through a series of images

Tags: mathematical-modeling, geometry, nudged-elastic-band

Cubic spline interpolation is used in a lot of methods like Nudged Elastic Band (NEB), or String or Growing String Method (GSM) either to reparameterize the path, or to estimate the position of the peak, or to find the path tangent (which is required for the force projection).

These splines represent a continuous path through all the images. So it would provide intermediate coordinates and energies for the entire pathway.

In most of the papers I have read, the spline interpolation is done with arc-length parameterisation. For example, the simplifiedd string method paper (W. E et al., J. Chem. Phys. 2007, 126, 164103) mentions that the arc lengths are calculated from the current images, and then fitted to a cubic spline. There is also the elastic image method paper (J. Chem. Theory Comput. 2022, 18, 8, 5108–5115) where they mention using a cubic spline on an interpolated path to find the peak, and then using lengths (arc lengths?) to move two images. The growing string paper (J. Chem. Phys. 2004, 120, 7877–7886) also performs cubic interpolation with arc lengths of the path for reparameterisation and growing the string and finding the interpolated (estimated) peak.

However, in all of these papers, I haven't found a single description of how the spline fitting and arc length parameterisation is actually performed from a set of Cartesian coordinates. Let's say that I have a series of Cartesian coordinates ($\vec{x}_A$, $\vec{x}_B$, $\vec{x}_C$, ...) each with the x, y and z of each atom, and an energy value. **How do I now calculate the arc length to fit the cubic spline, and how do I fit the energies?** The best I can do is to estimate the Euclidean distances between adjacent points ($||\vec{x}_A - \vec{x}_B||$), but that would not be the same as arc length as there is no guarantee that the spline would coincide with the linear path in Euclidean metric (basically norm of the vector subtraction).

Once I have the arc-length, it should be possible to fit the cubic spline with scipy's `CubicSpline` class, but I am still not sure how to deal with the energies and how to link them with the coordinates.

This seems like a such a simple thing that's used in all the methods, but I can't find the actual maths involved in the spline fitting anywhere. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: +1 but I'm not finding it clear what precisely you need to do and why you need to do it. I have always just used MATLAB's [spline function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) to build my splines. Even if I wanted to write that function myself out of academic curiosity, building splines does not involve any advanced mathematics and it has been done for several decades and procedures are [described in many places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, spline fitting functions are available in scipy, but what would be the parameter (x) for the spline through a series of images? How do you make it arc length parameterised? And how to predict the energies?

Comment: The question is not clear to me, because a spline is essentially a function that goes through some points. If you have the points, you can use MATLAB's spline function (or something similar) to build the spline. If you have a series of images, I think more details have to be given about what exactly you wish to interpolate.

Comment: @NikeDattani Have you ever NEB with reparameterisation or GSM? The cubic spline fits the coordinates and energies, and basically builds an approximation of the entire path from discrete images. This seems to be done routinely in NEB (available in ORCA code) / GSM and yet no one says how exactly to do it. That's what my question is about.

Comment: Google multidimensional spline and you'll get lots oh hits for the background theory. De Boor is the classic book, but there should be more accessible stuff out there

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/7013/5. I think that also if you were to strip out some of your question's body and make a precise mathematical statement of what specifically needs to be interpolated, it would not only help attract answers but it might also help you get closer to the answer on your own!

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of splines is that, as piecewise polynomials, they are cheap to interpolate. So here's how to numerically re-parametrise a spline by arc length:

1. Form a fine grid of the prior parameter (for example, decide that you will take ten points between each prior image).
2. Evaluate the spline at each grid point.
3. Estimate the cumulative arc-length at each grid point as the sum of Cartesian distances up to that point.

Now you have estimated the spline arc-length at each point on a fine grid of the prior parameter, which you can simply invert to estimate the prior parameter by arc-length -- an arc-length parametrisation!

The parametrisation accuracy can be checked by simply using finer grids. Since the spline and its derivatives are easily evaluated everywhere, the arc length accuracy can be obtained by analysing the Taylor error.

But the *fractional* arc-length will be even more accurately estimated. Both the total arc-length and the cumulative arc-length at each point will be underestimated by straight lines, and almost certainly by very similar proportions, so their ratio will almost certainly gain accuracy from cancellation of errors.

Having said that, when you say

> in all of these papers, I haven't found a single description of how the spline fitting and arc length parameterisation is actually performed from a set of Cartesian coordinates.

that simply isn't right. Both J. Chem. Phys. 2007, 126, 164103 (equation 12) and  J. Chem. Theory Comput. 2022, 18, 8, 5108–5115 (equation 5) state that the Cartesian distances between evaluated points is used as the arc-length estimate (even without sub-sampling!).

Comment: Thanks! one thing I am confused still, is that the Cartesian distance (Euclidean) won't be the same as the arc length presumably? So is it fine to use the Cartesian distance as the prior parameter for spline fitting and then sub-sample? Because you need the independent parameter for spline fitting in the first place.

Comment: "So is it fine to use the Cartesian distance as the prior parameter for spline fitting" -- I can't define what's fine or not, but it's certainly what those papers do. As George Box might say, all numerical calculations are approximate, but some are useful.

Comment: Both of the papers in the answer use fractional arc-length consistently to parametrise their splines, which also corresponds to a reaction co-ordinate (0 = reactant, 1 = product). So the _previous fractional arc-length_ would be available as the prior parameter.